# TFS how to create environment variables for several builds

Tags: tfs, build, environment-variables, azure-devops

I have a bunch of builds that use common information and I would like to maintain those in a single place.

I know there are variables at build level, but it's not suitable.
I tried adding a step with a batch that sets the environment variables I need but, at the next step, where they have to be used, they're no longer valid.
Is there any way to make them 'persistent' or a way to use variables common to all the builds ?

I had a look at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-a-build) 
but it does not indicate where to create the properties ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [Variable Set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/library/variable-groups) feature:

[image]

Alternatively, you can set custom variables from a PowerShell script using the set variable log syntax:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue"
```

Comment: sorry, I realize I made a mistake, I work on TFS 2015.

Comment: In that case the variable syntaxes from powershell is what you'll need.